# Launching external console application from Java

Tags: java, console, external

in a Java application I need to run an external console application. With the window's ones everything is OK:

```
try {
System.out.println("Running...");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
    System.out.println("End.");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

launches notepad successfully.

But if I put `D:\\MyProg.exe` or `.bat` or even `cmd.exe` (which is it PATH as notepad is) it does not work. Without any exeptions. Just:

```
Running...
End.
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, most likely `Runtime.exec()` is returning asynchronously, so just printing "end" will always work, since the exec call returns immediately, which is what you're seeing.

There's a bunch of other problems that could be showing up here. I think what is happening is that the programs you are calling might be outputting I/O on stdout that you are failing to read, or perhaps you need to [wait for it to finish](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) before exiting the java process. There's a [great article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) on the various problems with `Runtime.exec()` you should probably read, it covers this and other problems.

Answer (score -1):

It is because notepad placed in special folder and this folder exists in `Path` variable.

Run `cmd` using following line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start");
```

Run other application:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start C:\\path\\to\\app.exe");
```

Comment: but cmd.exe is also in "PATH". but it does not work. Also i preicse the path "D:\\MyProg.exe" but it does not help.
And where do i need to execute your "start" ? In java ???

Comment: Yeah, i'd like to, but as i mentioned above Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your.bat");
 does not work too

Comment: it just does not launch the *.bats

Comment: Check paths carefully. Make sure application **really** launches.

Comment: cmd is in PATH (checked by typing "cmd" anywhere); JAVA application passes by the instruction correctly: log is: "Running... End."; notepad also launches correctly. But the console applications do not...

Comment: in case of forgetting the path (for example "MyProg.bat" instead of "D:\\MyProg.bat") JAVA throws exeption. But if everything is OK the exeption is not thrown but the .bat is not ececuted.

Comment: If you are trying to launch console application, use: `cmd.exe /c start C:\\app.exe`.

Comment: Also tried. But due to "inlauchebility" of cmd.exe from JAVA it does nothing.

Comment: Try using full path to `cmd` (something like `C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c start`).